# Bulma - flexbox: Create specific behavior

Tags: css, flexbox, bulma

I would create [this](https://codepen.io/Hajerty/pen/abRLrJj) behavior with Bulma. I need to respect same width and for each width I have to visualize the box in 1, 2 or 3 columns.
When I resize the browser and the first column go to new line I need that the first is the second column and not the third.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.block-container {    
    -webkit-column-count:3;    
    -webkit-column-gap:10;    
  display:block;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
.item {
    background: green;
    padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: arial; 
    text-align: center;
    
}
@media (max-width:1024px) {
    .block-container {
        column-count: 1;
    }
  
}

@media (min-width:1025px) and (max-width:1649px) {
    .block-container {
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
    }

}

@media (min-width:1650px) {
    .block-container {
        -webkit-column-count: 3;
    }

}
```

```html
<div class="block-container">
    <div class="item first">1</div>
    <div class="item second">2</div>
    <div class="item third">3</div>
</div>
```

Anyone could realize this behavior with [bulma](https://bulma.io/documentation/) desing system?
Thanks

Comment: Sorry, your question is not clear. Can you try to edit your question in such way that it is more clear what you would like to achieve?

Comment: I would achieve the behavior in the sample with bulma design system.

Comment: It is worth clarifying that your example can only be reproduced in, at least, Chromium, since in Firefox it is displayed as vertically stacked columns _always_.